# Python : Bokeh : make frame invisible

Tags: python, bokeh

I am playing around with `Bokeh` for some time now and am really amazed how easy it is to create beautiful `charts`.

There is one visual thing I am not able to solve, however.

If I turn of background and borders **all my charts still have some kind of border / frame. Can you turn this off as well?**

E.g. If I use the following code to turn off my background, border and axis I still end up with a frame around the plot figure.

```
p.xaxis.visible = False
p.yaxis.visible = False 
p.xgrid.visible = False
p.ygrid.visible = False
p.background_fill_color = None
p.border_fill_color = None
```

Here is my [plot example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yrtvnsrdei6yhtn/Example.png?dl=0).

Any idea how to get rid of the `grey frame`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can remove it by setting p.outline_line_color to None.

Also by the way you can set p.axis.visible and p.grid.visible you don't need to specify the x and y axes separately

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. Works perfectly. Was a somewhat trivial question but I could not find an answer in the documentation.

Comment: Fore reference, it's here for the outline: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#outline and here for the axes properties: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#axes If there is something that would make those better somehow please let us know (or best: submit a PR to improve them)

Comment: @bigreddot Thanks. Sorry...I should have found it myself...And thanks for putting some much effort into Bokeh. I am quite a python novice and it enables me to create so many things with so little effort. Really amazing.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. No apologies needed, our docs are fairly extensive, but I think they might be sometimes hard to navigate, which is why suggestions are always welcome!